# Silverstripe create unordered list from CheckboxSetField values (many_many)

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I'm learning, but I've hit another wall so I have another question...

So I've created a DataObject with all of the company's plan features and I'm displaying all of those features as checkboxes with `CheckboxSetField` whenever a new membership plan type is created so the user doesn't have to wrangle the HTML editor field.

All that is set up and working fine, the only trouble is that when I ask for the values of the check boxes to display the list of plan features I get a single comma separated list... That's no good as I need to be able to take each selected feature and display it as a list item (`<li> ... </li>`).

Right now it's returning lists like **1 ,2** and **2 ,3** which are the IDs of the selected plan features. I'm hesitant to set the value of the checkbox to the text string of the plan feature, so I was going to use those IDs to reference the records from the `PlanFeature` table. Is there a better way of doing it? I think I need a control to explode this list at the very least ...

I've spend a solid couple hours trying (and failing) to get this working and I think I need some help. Since I have no idea how to get the items out of this list I haven't begun to explore how to display the content in the template either so I may possibly need some help there as well. Thanks in advance :)

Here's my code.

**PlanFeature.php**

```
<?php

class PlanFeature extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array (
        'PlanFeatureText' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array (
        'PlanFeature' => 'Pricing',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array (
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'PlanFeatureText' => 'Plan Feature',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('PlanFeatureText')
        );
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**ServicePlan.php** *in getCMSFields()*

```
..//

CheckboxSetField::create(
    'PlanFeatures',
    'Choose Your Plan Features',
    PlanFeature::get()->map('ID', 'PlanFeatureText')
),

..//
```

**Pricing.php**

```
<?php
class Pricing extends Page {
private static $has_many = array (
    'ServicePlans' => 'ServicePlan'
);

private static $many_many = array (
    'PlanFeatures' => 'PlanFeature'
);

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Plans', GridField::create(
        'ServicePlans',
        'Orenda Force Service Plan Information',
        $this->ServicePlans(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ));
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Plans', GridField::create(
        'PlanFeatures',
        'Manage Plan Features',
        $this->PlanFeatures(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ));

    return $fields;
    }
}

class Pricing_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

*And here's where I got completely lost ... so I'm sure that none of this is right :(*

**Page.php** *(in Page_Controller)*

```
function ExplodedFeatures() {
    $set = new DataObjectSet();

    if($Features = Pricing::get()->First()->PlanFeatures) {
        foreach(explode(',',$Features) as $key => $value) {
            $set->push(new ArrayData(array('Value' => $value)));
        }
    }

echo $set;
}

public function Features() {
    $Feature = Pricing::get();
    $Feature = $Feature->PlanFeatures()->getOptions();
    return $Feature;
    //return $Feature;
}
```

**Pricing.ss**

```
<section class="body pricing">
    <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title-02 text-monochrome">Pricing</h2>
        <% loop $ServicePlans %>
            <div class="col-1-3 card pricing">
                <div class="pricing__header $PlanColor">
                    <p class="pricing__plan-name">$PlanName</p>
                    <p class="pricing__price">$PlanPrice<sub>$PlanRenewal</sub></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__contents">
                    <h3 class="title-06">Plan details</h3>
                    <ul>
                    <% loop $PlanFeatures %>
                      <li>$PlanFeatureText</li>
                    <% end_loop %>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end_loop %>
        $Content
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds similarly structured to the following. Perhaps these are the relationships/template structures you are looking for?

1. https://github.com/assertchris/so-29584213/blob/master/mysite/code/Pricing.php
2. https://github.com/assertchris/so-29584213/blob/master/mysite/code/models/Plan.php
3. https://github.com/assertchris/so-29584213/blob/master/mysite/code/models/Feature.php
4. https://github.com/assertchris/so-29584213/blob/master/themes/simple/templates/Layout/Pricing.ss

Comment: That looks like it would cover it, how do I get all that on the homepage as well though?

Comment: You'd need to add a method to your HomePage_Controller that'll grab all of the `Plan`s.

https://gist.github.com/edlinklater/b9806d2b82b464f333b5

Then you can use the exact same code as in the Pricing.ss provided by @assertchris

Comment: I'm still getting the data returned to me as a comma separated list. Here's a screenshot of the database and the UI for selecting the options ...

Comment: [databse](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucfu8yhrvvhaj0l/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-12%20at%2010.21.17%20AM.png?dl=0)

[CMS ui](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oueyaziv4dyt1wz/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-12%20at%2010.21.34%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a link to the source code?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/dwashburn/orendaforce I can add you to the repo for access. I managed to create a function on `page.php` that turns the list created by the checkbox field into an array then uses those values to get the record from the database. I'm thinking I need to get those values into an array to reference in the template... I'm not sure that I'm doing this right, it's probably more than likely an overly complex solution.

Comment: Update: I finished the function to create an ArrayList with the proper records and I can loop through it on the home page and pricing page, but only when it's outside of a loop ...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to write any code in your `Page_Controller`, as there is already a relationship between `Pricing` and `PlanFeature`.

In the template for `Pricing` (which I note is a Pagetype), you should be able to generate a list of values of `PlanFeature`s using:

```
<ul>
<% loop $PlanFeatures %>
  <li>$PlanFeatureText</li>
<% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works fine when I'm only displaying one membership plan, I have to display 3 though so I'm getting the content from a loop in both the homepage and the pricing page ... I'll add Pricing.ss to the code above.

Needing access to the info on the home page had me thinking that I needed a controller, am I wrong?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any relationship between `ServicePlan` and `PlanFeature`. Could you describe the real-world relationship between each `Pricing`, `ServicePlan` and `PlanFeature`?